# is there a built-in feature to say a dict A contains another dict B?

Tags: python

e.g. dict `a` contains dict `b1` because:

```
a = { 'name': 'mary', 'age': 56, 'gender': 'female' }
b1 = { 'name': 'mary', 'age': 56 }
```

But this is False because the value for the key `name` is different.

```
b2 = { 'name': 'elizabeth', 'age': 56 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This "shortcircuits". When the first item of `b2` is found that isn't in `a`, the `all()` terminates immediately. Also avoids the memory overhead of creating temporary sets

```
>>> a = { 'name': 'mary', 'age': 56, 'gender': 'female' }
>>> b1 = { 'name': 'mary', 'age': 56 }
>>> 
>>> all(a[k]==v for k,v in b1.iteritems())
True
>>> b2 = { 'name': 'elizabeth', 'age': 56 }
>>> all(a[k]==v for k,v in b2.iteritems())
False
```

In the case that `b` contains keys that aren't in `a`, you can use this

```
>>> all(a.get(k, object())==v for k,v in b2.iteritems())
False
```

Comment: And it works on any dict, even if it contains something unhashable like a list.

Comment: +1, with the caveat that this raises an exception when a key `k` is not found in `a`.

Comment: as a safeguard and optional performance optimization in case there are keys of `b1` that are not in a, I'd do the check as `all(a[k]==v for k,v in b1.iteritems() if k in a)`

Comment: @larsmans is right, I would change `a[k]==v` to `k in a and a[k]==v`

Comment: @digEmAll `has_key` is deprecated. Use `in`.

Comment: @digEmAll: you must mean `k in a`. `has_key` is deprecated.

Comment: I like the `get(k, object())` solution, though I'm not sure I'd recommend it to novice Pythonistas...

Comment: @larsmans, It's a handy way to avoid race conditions if it ever ends up in some threaded code

Answer (score 7):

```
set(b1.iteritems()) <= set(a.iteritems())
```

`<=` implements the subset relation on [`set` objects](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set). This works when both the keys and the values in both dicts are hashable (strings, tuples and ints are, lists are not).

Comment: `set(b1.iteritems()).issubset(a.iteritems())` avoids converting `a.iteritem()` to a set

Comment: @gnibbler, no, it doesn't: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e5e53f30b2ed/Objects/setobject.c#l1745

Comment: If you want to avoid constructing both sets, you'd use a comprehension: `bset = set(b1.iteritems()); print all(x in bset for x in a.iteritems())`. But it's probably slower than going with the built-in set comparison...

Answer (score 2):

I am going to answer if the dictionaries are compatible so I've changed the sample:

```
>>> test_compat = lambda d1, d2: all(d1[k]==d2[k] for k in set(d1) & set(d2))
>>> a = { 'name': 'mary', 'age': 56, 'gender': 'female' }
>>> b1 = { 'name': 'mary', 'age': 56, 'phone' : '555' }
>>> b2 = { 'name': 'elizabeth', 'age': 56 }
>>> test_compat(a, b1) 
True
>>> test_compat(a, b2)
False
>>> test_compat(b1, a)
True
```

The `set(d1) & set(d2)`  is an intersection of all the keys between the two dictionaries. `all` will early out of any of the corresponding values mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** there is a built-in function. [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) returns a view of the dictionary that behaves pretty much like a `set`:

```
In [1]: a = { 'name': 'mary', 'age': 56, 'gender': 'female' }
   ...: b1 = { 'name': 'mary', 'age': 56 }
   ...: 

In [2]: b1.items() <= a.items()
Out[2]: True

In [3]: b2 = { 'name': 'elizabeth', 'age': 56 }

In [4]: b2.items() <= a.items()
Out[4]: False
```

The operators `<`, `<=` `>=` and `>` have the same meaning as for `set`s.

In python2.7 you can access the views of the `dict`s using the [`viewitems()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewitems) method.

This is much better than explicitly convert the items to a `set` (as in the other proposed answers) because:

- It works with unhashable values:

  ```
  In [10]: a = {'a': [1]}
      ...: set(a.items()) <= set(a.items())
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-10-893acb4047c9> in <module>()
        1 a = {'a': [1]}
  ----> 2 set(a.items()) <= set(a.items())

  TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
  ```

  While:

  ```
  In [11]: a.items() <= a.items()
  Out[11]: True
  ```
- It is more memory efficient since it doesn't require any other allocation. Using a `set` *might* double the memory used.
- It is faster (since it avoids the overhead of a new allocation).

---

Simple benchmark with the proposed solutions (in python2):

```
In [1]: a = {'a'+str(i): i for i in range(500000)}
   ...: b = a.copy()
   ...: 

In [2]: %timeit set(a.iteritems()) <= set(b.iteritems())
1 loops, best of 3: 810 ms per loop

In [3]: %timeit all(a[k]==v for k,v in b.iteritems())
10 loops, best of 3: 157 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit all(a.get(k,object())==v for k,v in b.iteritems())
1 loops, best of 3: 237 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit a.viewitems() <= b.viewitems()
10 loops, best of 3: 80.8 ms per loop

In [6]: def test_compat(d1, d2):
   ...:     return all(d1[k]==d2[k] for k in set(d1) & set(d2))
   ...: 
   ...: def test_compat2(d1, d2):
   ...:     return all(d1[k] == d2[k] for k in d1.viewkeys() & d2.viewkeys())
   ...: 

In [7]: %timeit test_compat(a, b)
1 loops, best of 3: 514 ms per loop

In [8]: %timeit test_compat2(a, b)
1 loops, best of 3: 500 ms per loop
```

`viewitems()` is about 2x faster than the second fastest solution.